how to change the default number of items per page
I'd like to change the default amount of items displayed in a list (25 currently).
I'm using SonataBundle 4.x
I have looked in the doc unsuccessfully.
Thanks
edit :
i have found my answer,
in the admin class, we can override the following function :
protected function configureDefaultSortValues(array &$sortValues): void
{
    $sortValues[DatagridInterface::PER_PAGE] = 250;
}


To change the default number of items displayed per page in a SonataAdminBundle list in Symfony, you need to configure the max_per_page option in your SonataAdmin configuration.

i can't find anything regarding that configuration, and it's not clear in which config file to put it. Do you have any link to the documentation regarding that ? Thanks
